# Jenkins Upload Build Error

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play-services

I'm trying to use `JENKINS` to build and upload my `apk`. It builds, but would always give the error below:

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

`Total time: 2 mins 52.793 secs`
`Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS`
`Archiving artifacts`
`Upload failed: This service is not available from your country`
`- No changes have been applied to the Google Play account`
`Build step 'Upload Android APK to Google Play' marked build as failure`

What can I do

Comment: How are you trying to upload your APK? It seems that Google Play is returning that error to an API call. It is not something that Jenkins is failing to do.

Comment: I use `JENKINS` `GOOGLE PLAY PLUGIN`

Comment: And followed the instructions here [YouTube Help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txdPSJF94RM&list=PLhF0STyfNdUk1R3taEmgFR30yzp41yuRK&index=1) @yasarix

Comment: As far as I can see from the plugin source code, this error is not generated by the plugin itself, instead, Google is returning it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty self explanatory

`Upload failed: This service is not available from your country`

Google API is checking the geo-location of your IP address, and is refusing to serve your country.

You can get around this if you configure some system level (not browser level) proxy that will make your  IP appear as if it's from US, Canada, or some EU country